# How to produce different builds for different dependencies (Hadoop 0.23.9, 2.0.0, etc) with maven

Tags: java, maven, hadoop

I'm going to finish a small oss [project](http://nchadoop.org/) to browse hdfs on the cli (like ncdu). Now I need to solve how to ship it with different dependencies (because there are different distributions of hadoop).

For my use-case their Java APIs are the same, so theoretically I just need to replace the some dependencies and build them one by one. Including all the unit test and deployment stuff its not handy to do it by hand.

Is there a way to execute the `mvn install` 3 times with different versions?

I need to build it with this with this versions (not that the cdh ones having different dependencies):

- 0.23.9
- 2.0.0-cdh4.2.0
- 2.0.0-cdh4.3.0

---

The only solution I came up with, is to have thee profiles and then let the CI execute `mvn install` 3 times with different profiles.

Like this:

```
mvn install -Phadoop-vanillia-0.23.9
mvn install -Phadoop-cdh4.2.0
mvn install -Phadoop-cdh4.3.0
```

My pom.xml for that looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <!-- ... -->
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>hadoop-vanillia-0.23.9</id>
            <properties>
                <hadoop-distribution>vinallia-0.23.9</hadoop-distribution>
                <hadoop.version.generic>0.23.9</hadoop.version.generic>
            </properties>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
                    <version>${hadoop.version.generic}</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
                    <version>${hadoop.version.generic}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>hadoop-cdh4.2.0</id>
            <properties>
                <hadoop-distribution>cdh4.2.0</hadoop-distribution>
                <hadoop.version.generic>2.0.0-cdh4.2.0</hadoop.version.generic>
                <hadoop.version.mr1>2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.2.0</hadoop.version.mr1>
            </properties>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
                    <version>${hadoop.version.generic}</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
                    <version>${hadoop.version.generic}</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hadoop-tools</artifactId>
                    <version>${hadoop.version.mr1}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>

            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>cloudera</id>
                    <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/</url>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>hadoop-cdh4.3.0</id>
            <properties>
                <hadoop-distribution>hadoop-cdh4.3.0</hadoop-distribution>
                <hadoop.version.generic>2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.3.0</hadoop.version.generic>
            </properties>
            <!-- Same then 4.2.0 here ... -->
        </profile>

    </profiles>

    <properties>
        <!-- ... -->
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- ... -->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <!-- ... -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <programs>
                        <program>
                            <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
                            <name>nchadoop</name>
                        </program>

                        <!-- put the flavours into different folders: -->
                        <assembleDirectory>${project.build.directory}/appassembler/${hadoop-distribution}/</assembleDirectory>
                    </programs>

                    <!-- ... -->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Any Ideas how to do this more elegant? Maybe with modules?

Comment: Would it work to build your main module against one of them, mark the latter as `provided` and then make (three) downstream projects that depend on the main project and actually declare the right dependencies accordingly?

Comment: How are you going to invoke your script? I would say if they are all API compatible then depend on the lowest version (provided scope) and then as part of your installation procedure make the user configure their actual hadoop installation location (so you can add the correct jar to the classpath at runtime)

Comment: The plan was to provide 3 ready to go tar balls. With this the user just need to download and extract them. I could also think about deb or yum packages but o think that's overkill